# jQuery Fade Images on iPhone Issue

Tags: jquery, iphone

I want the thumbnails on my website to fade in when loaded rather than load the traditional way.  I'm using jQuery to achieve this by setting the opacity of each img to 0 in CSS, then fading it up to 1 using jQuery like so:

```
image.bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeTo(1000, 1); });
```

This works fine in a desktop browser, but in Mobile Safari or Chrome on the iPhone, the fading of the images stutters as if the loading and the fading is all performed in the same thread and the loading blocks the animation.  I suspect this could be exactly what's going on and that I'll just have to live with it, but I'm posting here in the hope that someone has a hack or clever way around it.

I've tried covering each image with an opaque div and fading that to transparent instead, but it produces the same result.

You can see it in action at: http://www.anthonyburns.co.uk

Comment: .fadeIn() doesn't work at all - I think it expects display:none for fadeIn() to work, but I need my img set to display:block - hence I'm setting opacity to 0, then using fadeTo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your having frame rate issues using .fadeTo()

I would recommend using the CSS3 transition effects built into Safari to get that nice smooth fade in you're looking for: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Introduction.html

Comment: Brilliant!  Works perfectly, and for completeness, I used the following article to detect if transitions are supported and fall back to jQuery if they're not: http://technology.razorfish.com/2010/02/08/detecting-css-transitions-support-using-javascript/